# Auto increment counter if field length is greater than n

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment

I have been asked to include a field ComNo, and if field length of Comments is greater than 5 characters, the rest of characters in Comment should appear in next line and  ComNo field should be incremented by one

Input

```
EmpID EmpName ServiceNumber Date         Comments
1     a      123            23-03-1990   wednesday
1     a      1234           24-04-1990   Test12
2     b      234            24-05-2016   Todayis
```

And the expected output is

```
EmpID EmpName ServiceNumber Date       ComNo Comments
1     a       123           23-03-1990 1     wedne
1     a       123           23-03-1990 2     sday
1     a       1234          24-04-1990 1     Test1
1     a       1234          24-04-1990 2     2
2     b       234           24-05-2016 1     Today
2     b       234           24-05-2016 2     is
```

I have an idea how to implement this using plsql procedure but can we implement the same using sql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that makes no prior assumptions about the length of comments. I added two strings, one short (less than 5 characters) and one longer than 10 characters, as well as one with NULL comment to make sure the row is not lost, to test the solution thoroughly.

I assume `(empid, dt)` is a unique combination (perhaps primary key) in the base table. By the way, I hope you are not actually using `Date` as a column name in your schema.

The solution does not contain the WITH clause; it begins at `select empid...` The ORDER BY clause may not be needed either.

```
with
     test_data ( empid, empname, servicenumber, dt, comments ) as (
       select 1, 'a',  123, to_date('23-03-1990', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'wednesday'   from dual union all
       select 1, 'a', 1234, to_date('24-04-1990', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'Test12'      from dual union all
       select 2, 'b',  234, to_date('24-05-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'Todayis'     from dual union all
       select 2, 'b',  235, to_date('25-05-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'Joe'         from dual union all
       select 3, 'c',  238, to_date('25-05-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), ''            from dual union all
       select 4, 'c', 2238, to_date('25-05-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'longer string' from dual
     )
select empid, empname, servicenumber, dt, level as comno,
       substr(comments, 5 * level - 4, 5) as comments
from   test_data
connect by level <= 1 + length(comments) / 5
     and   prior empid = empid
     and   prior dt    = dt
     and   prior sys_guid() is not null
order by empid, dt
;

     EMPID E SERVICENUMBER DT              COMNO COMMENTS
---------- - ------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 a           123 1990-03-23          1 wedne
         1 a           123 1990-03-23          2 sday
         1 a          1234 1990-04-24          1 Test1
         1 a          1234 1990-04-24          2 2
         2 b           234 2016-05-24          1 Today
         2 b           234 2016-05-24          2 is
         2 b           235 2016-05-25          1 Joe
         3 c           238 2016-05-25          1
         4 c          2238 2016-05-25          1 longe
         4 c          2238 2016-05-25          2 r str
         4 c          2238 2016-05-25          3 ing
```

**Added**: If your data is of CLOB data type, it is better to use the `dbms_lob` version of `substr`. Also, if you must chop the data into 75 character segments, you must adjust several numbers. Here is the same solution, with these two changes and without the ORDER BY clause (not needed if this is used to migrate the data to another db product). NOTE: `dbms_lob.substr()` has the "amount" and the "offset" (second and third arguments) reversed compared to the usual `substr()` function; notice that when you compare the solutions.

```
select empid, empname, servicenumber, dt, level as comno,
       dbms_lob.substr(comments, 75, 75 * level - 74) as comments
from   test_data
connect by level <= 1 + length(comments) / 75
     and   prior empid = empid
     and   prior dt    = dt
     and   prior sys_guid() is not null
;
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute force option would be to just `UNION` together the records resulting from splitting the comments by 5 characters at a time:

```
SELECT EmpID, EmpName, ServiceNumber, Date, 1, SUBSTR(Comments, 1, 5) AS Comments
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT EmpID, EmpName, ServiceNumber, Date, 2, SUBSTR(Comments, 6, 5) AS Comments
FROM yourTable
WHERE SUBSTR(Comments, 6, 5) <> ''  -- but don't show a record if
UNION ALL                           -- all characters already used
...
```

Comment: @AnnieJeba Then have a look at Gordon's answer.  By the way, why do you need to do this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114

Comment: @mathguy Why on earth did I think the OP was using Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n from dual union all
      select 2 from dual
     )
select EmpID, EmpName, ServiceNumber, Date, ComNo,
       substr(comments, n.n * 5 - 4, 5) as Comments
from t join
     n
     on length(comments) >= n.n * 5 + 1;
```

Note:  Your example only has comments up to 10 characters, so only the values 1 and 2 are needed for `n`.  You can create additional rows by expanding `n`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply. My example has comments only up to 10 characters but actual data has comments more than 4000 characters.

Comment: @AnnieJeba . . . This solution is easily extended just in case that was the case.  I do note, however, that Oracle limits strings to 4,000 characters, so I'd be surprised if they are longer than that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Oracle documentation of CLOB data type: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i3237

Comment: @AnnieJeba - if your data is CLOB, you may benefit from using the dbms_lob package (the "lob versions" of `substr` and `instr`). https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#BABEAJAD  Question though: If the comments may be thousands of characters, why chop them into five character fragments? Why five and not, for example, 80?

Comment: The actual requirement is to chop the comments to 75 characters in each line, since the sample data will go huge i just mentioned as 5 characters. They are loading data from Oracle to SAP DB and the field length limitation in SAP is 75 chars and so i was asked to extract the report in coherence with how they load data to SAP

Comment: @AnnieJeba . . . Just use this approach and generate a sufficient number of numbers to break up your comments.